# Upload a file with curl using POST, but simulating a HTML submit

Tags: php, c, post, curl, libcurl

I have the following C code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  struct stat file_info;
  double speed_upload, total_time;
  FILE *fd;

  fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); /* open file to upload */
  if(!fd) {

    return 1; /* can't continue */
  }

  /* to get the file size */
  if(fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0) {

    return 1; /* can't continue */
  }

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* upload to this place */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                     "http://www.website.com/index.php");

    /* tell it to "upload" to the URL */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

    /* set where to read from (on Windows you need to use READFUNCTION too) */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);

    /* and give the size of the upload (optional) */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    /* enable verbose for easier tracing */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    }
    else {
      /* now extract transfer info */
      curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &speed_upload);
      curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &total_time);

      fprintf(stderr, "Speed: %.3f bytes/sec during %.3f seconds\n",
              speed_upload, total_time);

    }
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and the following PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
    if( isset( $_FILES["file_entry"] ) )
    {
    print "file ok";
    }
    else
    {
    print "no file sent";
    }
}
else
{
    print "No post method" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
}
?>
```

and html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file_entry"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to send the file by html, it works fine, but not when I use C and cURL.
Because I don't know how I can send "file_entry".  How can I emulate submit "file_entry" with C cURL like html does?  I try use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but don't work.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you

Comment: There is no C++, it's C only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your server end expects a "multipart/form-data" POST and you send a regular "url-encoded" one.

You should instead look into for example the [multi-post.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html) example or the [curl_formadd](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html)() documentation.

Alternatively you change the server end.

Comment: I try change the method to "CURLOPT_UPLOAD", but dont works too.  There is a easy way using my C code?  Implementing only a few changes?  Because the sample "multi-post.c" is very hard to me understand.

Comment: I've responded to the question. How to fix the code to do the form post upload. If you now suddenly want to do something else, then sure you need some other code but then it is no longer this question so I'm sorry but I will not continue going down that route as a comment here... !